# how to debug salt and salt-call issue?

Tags: salt

I encountered a strange phenomenon, the running results of salt and salt-call were inconsistent.
run `salt -l debug minion1 state.apply createnewpath.jobs` get error

```
ID: createnewpath_jobs_6
    Function: file.directory
        Name: /jobs/upadm
      Result: False
     Comment: User upadm is not available
     Started: 17:01:42.544322
    Duration: 1.113 ms
     Changes:
```

run `salt-call -l debug state.apply createnewpath.jobs` on minion1. Runs normally without errors.

How can I debug this issue.

And this is sls for createnewpath.jobs

```
createnewpath_jobs_6:
  file.directory:
    - name: /jobs/upadm
    - user: upadm
    - group: 1020
    - file_mode: 664
    - dir_mode: 775
    - makedirs: True
```